# Help required: Root finding algorithm with guaranteed rate of convergence for two Quadratic equations

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, algorithms, roots

Consider two equations over two variables (in Reals) of the form:

$$f(x,y)= A_0[term 1]+A_1[term 2]+A_2[term 3]+A_3[term 4]+A_4$$

$$g(x,y)= B_0[term 1]+B_1[term 2]+B_2[term 3]+B_3[term 4]+B_4$$

where $A_0..A_4$ and $B_0..B_4$ are some real constants.

The maximum "degree of freedom" of each term in both equations is 2. The equations are not necessarily simple polynomials. It can also include trigonometric identities like sin(x), cos(y) etc. For eg (just a random example):

$$f(x,y):sin(x)∗cos(y)+sin(3x)−12*cos(5y)+.3=0$$

$$g(x,y):x−3y-.1=0$$

The terms and their "degree of freedom" would be as follows:

$$sin(x)∗cos(y), sin(3x), -12*cos(5y), .3: (2, 1, 1, 0)$$

$$x, 3y, .1: (1, 1, 0)$$

**Query:** Assuming this system of equations has a solution. Let x_0, y_0 be our initial guesses and the error or distance from 0 for each equation be E_0, E_1 respectively.

I tried Newton Raphson but it seems to work only when:

1. our guess is very close to x, y.
2. there is no guarantee that it will converge.
3. there is no guaranteed rate of convergence.

Can some one help with the fastest known approach that is guaranteed to find a solution and has a guaranteed rate of convergence? By guaranteed rate of convergence we mean that there is a guarantee that for example error will half after some f() steps, where f() is some function defined over the two equations.

Comment: If one equation is linear as in your example, the problem is simple.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That is just an example. As I stated the generic/worst case is the each one is quadratic with 5 terms each.

Comment: For sure, I understood. What I try to mean is that if you can express $y$ as a function (even complicated) of $x$ the problem is "simple"

Comment: Thank you. Since each var is independent of the other: you are suggesting having something like y=p(x) and y=q(x) and then solving right? but that might not always be possible. For example: $$(cos(x)-A)^2 + (cos(y)-B)^2=0$$.

Comment: The major problem with democracy is that we are allowed to disagree ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I am a layman so please don't get offended! and if I did due apologies. How will we deal with equations like above? Can you please explain/help? (A and B are some constants as usual)

Comment: Oh ! Be sure that I am not offended at all. I shall try to do something with the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144898/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-xyz).

Answer (score 1):

Given the arbitrariness of the terms you are adding up in the equations, it is pointless to even consider them... The structure does not rule out any functions $f(x,y), g(x,y)$.

In fact, as it is currently written, you are asking for a method that will surely work of any given system with two equations and two unknowns, and with a guaranteed rate of convergence. Let me save you some time: This does not exist.

If you are able to provide actual restrictions on the choice of $f$ and $g$, maybe something can be said.

Comment: Thank you. The arbitrariness is due to the fact that I am considering any pair of equations with max 2 degrees of freedom (lets say a super set of degree 2 polynomials of the same form). Yes the interpretation is correct. When you say "This does not exist". Does that also include "This/such an algo cannot exist" backed by some proof or just that "its not known". Secondly, is there an approach that works in "many" or "most" cases if not all? I tried Newton Raphson but as i said too limited.

Comment: Lets restrict ourselves to form where 1st equation is any possible f(x,y) and g(x,y) is the $$(cos(x)-A)^2 + (cos(y)-B)^2=0$$. What about this form?

Comment: @xyz That particular choice for $g$ does not even require a numerical method... The only possible solutions must satisfy $\cos x = A$ and $\cos y = B$. So, if both $A$ and $B$ are in $[-1,1]$, you can compute all possible pairs $(x,y)$ and then plug them into the first equation to see if they are an actual solution.

Comment: won't the all possible pair be infinite (real) here?! Secondly there will be 2 equations, so a chosen (x,y) would have to satisfy the first equation as well?! so i am unclear how we go about it

Comment: @xyz If $A,B\in[-1,1]$ there will be an infinite number of pairs $(x,y)$ that solve the second equation, for which you can actually get an explicit formula. If one of these pairs satisfy the first equation, the system will have a solution, if none of these pairs satisfy the first equation, the system has no solutions.

Comment: For example, if you consider the equation $(\cos x -1)^2 + (\cos y-1)^2 = 0$, the solutions (to the second equation) are all pairs of the form $(2 k_1 \pi, 2 k_2 \pi)$ with $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose now that the first equation was $x y  = 1$... The system would be impossible, because $4 k_1 k_2 \pi^2$ can never be 1.

Comment: thank you. I get the concept. But, if possible can you help with an example. Say A=cos(2.5) and B=cos(20.5), how do we go about this creating formula? I am struggling a bit here to see how it goes. please feel free to choose any f(x,y) or its fine if we ignore it too for the time being.

Comment: aah i was just typing a request:) I understand the impossibility case. but what about a non trivial possibility case/problem? what i mean is if f(x,y) is generic as in the original Q and g(x,y) is this^ is the problem "easy"?

Comment: Can you please clarify if this approach generalize for any quadratic f(x,y) (as described in original Q) and this specific g(x,y) to find a solution efficiently? Cause the way I see is we can end up with 3 equations and 4 unknowns?

Comment: hi. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @xyz If $g(x,y) =(\cos x -A)^2 + (\cos y -B)^2$, you can analytically solve the system no matter what $f(x,y)$ might be. I have no idea what you are talking abiut when you mention 3 equations and four unknowns. You need to take some time and really think what are your actual unknowns and what are the (known) parameters you are using in the consttuction of $f, g$.

Comment: thank a ton. due apologies for testing your patience but please bear with me for a little while as i am struggling. for the $g(x)$ the generic value (an example for what you have given) easily obtained (www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Arccos_Calculator.html) where $$k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$ are two integer variables. That part is clear. Now let f(x) be another function: For example: $$f(x)=x^2 - Cy - D$$ where C and D are some constants. We know the value of x and y is of a specific form. But this pair also has to satisfy f(x). Now how do I approach it I am struggling to see?

Comment: the 4 unknowns I mentioned are $$x, y, K_1, k_2$$ the 3 equations I mentioned would be $f(x)$ that still needs to be satisfied and generic form of values of $x$ and $y$ in terms of an equation involving $$k_1, K_2$$ respectively. I don't know how to proceed from here. I can replace x and y in f(x) with their generic values in form of($$k_1, k_2$$). But this equation would have to be solved for integer $$k_1, k_2$$. How do we do that?

Comment: if possible can you please clarify?